# Notepad++ RegExp

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am working with a text file that I need to re-elaborate in Python but before I needto have a dictionary and I'd like to create it using replace function in notepad++.

My text file looks like:

```
Item 1.
Text Text
Text 

Item 2.
Text

[...]

Item 1005.
Text

Text
Text
Item 1006. Text
```

I would like to have:

```
"Item 1":"TextTextText","Item 2":"Text",
```

and so on

I've thought about:

Replace \r\n => blank

Replace: Item (.+).(.+)[NOT Item] => "\1":"\2",

But I am not sure which is the command to make it stop the second time it finds the word "Item" without including it.

It's my very first time. Would you mind helping me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two passes.

First pass: replace `\s+` with an empty string, as you did.

Second pass:

```
(Item\.?)(\d+)\.?(.*?)(?=Item\.?\d+|\Z)
```

```
"$1 $2":"$3",
```

`.*?` is *lazy*, it will try to match as few characters as possible, but the lookahead `(?=Item\d+\.|\Z)` forces it to match either until it's followed by another `Item\d+\.` or the end of the string (`\Z`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful. But what if I have, e.g.,
Item. 1005
Text Text
Text 
[=Item (point) number (text)]
and I want "Item. 1005":"Text Text Text", ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fregior you can tweak the regex accordingly to your needs. I've edited my answer but you may have to further change it to fit your needs.